# Run java code in multiple jvm instances

Tags: java, testing, concurrency, jvm

I have a windows service application and a client which communicates with service using RMI. 
I need to do some concurrency testing with multiple clients but I need every client runs to different jvm instance because there are some static variables in its code. 
Can I do that ? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you need each client to run on its own JVM? i.e. can't you just let run concurrent RMI clients in a single JVM's thread pool?

Comment: There are some static variables in the client's code so there are some conflicts when I run more than one client in the same jvm instance.

Comment: I bet you know about ThreadLocal, but are as lazy as I am. Simply copying the JRE directory N times should do.

Comment: OP: Fix them then right? i.e. ensure the thread safety of all shared mutable state.

Comment: There are dozens of java files with static variables, so it is not very realistic to change all these files. Thanks! – user1540341

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using JDI - [VirtualMachineManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/index.html) (which you can get by calling `Bootstrap.virtualMachineManager();`) provides (at least one) [launching connector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/index.html). You can then call `launch();` on this connector which provides you with a [VM mirror](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/VirtualMachine.html) for the VM it creates. This mirror then lets you remotely execute methods on this VM.

You can set up as many remote VMs using this method as you choose, though obviously there's a relatively big performance penalty for doing things this way, and it's a fair bit of effort. Unless the effort would be astronomical, I'd personally advocate fixing the code to guarantee thread safety (using `ThreadLocal`) and then you do away with the need to worry about JDI (or a similar setup.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a shell script to spawn a new client with its own set of parameters in a loop.

But, in general. Running client code in several VMs just because there are some static variables being shared is definitely not a good solution. The **fundamental problem is in your client code**, as already suggested, you could use `ThreadLocal`, `ThreadPools`, or some synchronization logic to isolate a set of variables between various client threads.