# How to use two versions of jar in my java project

Tags: java, jar, version, classloader, conflict

In my java project, I need to use **neo4j-1.9.3** that depends on **lucene-3.6.2**, and **ElasticSearch**  which depends on **lucene-4.4.0**.  I know that if I want to use two versions of lucene directly, I can use ClassLoader to load different classes from the lucenes.

But the problem is that I won't use lucene's apis directly now. Is there any way that lucene-3.6.2 can be loaded when neo4j's apis are running, and lucene-4.4.0 can be loaded while running elasticsearch's apis. The two versions of lucene conflict now, and I need to run neo4j and elasticsearch in one project. How could I solve the dependency problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem trying to use lucene-core-4.3.1.jar for LUCENE and lucene-core-3.6.2.jar for embedded neo4j database but neo4j breaks with lucene-core-4.3.1.jar. How did you resolve your issue?

Comment: yes me too I have the same problem plz let us know how did you solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still use a ClassLoader solution, but that is a nasty business where it is easy to make mistakes.

You could also use different JVM's.

But the solution I would personally choose is either (or both) of the following:

- Verify that Neo4J breaks with Lucene 4.x. Maybe you will get lucky and there won't be any problems using the latest version.
- Split them up into two applications where one of them, say Neo4J, is accessed by the other application via web service (most likely REST) calls. Neo4J has a built-in [REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api.html) anyway.

Comment: yeah, I will try to solve it by updating neo4j or splitting them. But could tell me more about the ClassLoader solution or how to use different JVM's? I just wanna learn these. Thanks

Comment: They are theoretically possible solutions, but I found them more touble than they're worth for my purposes. Here are references: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714043/run-java-code-in-multiple-jvm-instances

Answer (score 1):

OSGi can fix this problem. An OSGi bundle is nothing more than a jar with additional metadata detailing versions. A bundle has a version number, and will detail version numbers (or ranges) of dependent jars.