# lucene-core-3.6.2 in Neo4j conflict with lucene-core-4.3.1 in my current project

Tags: lucene, neo4j, dependencies

I am using `Lucene 4.x.` in my project which requires `Lucene-core-4.3.1`. Recently I began exploring Neo4j database in maintaining a graph of my data. `lucene-core-3.6.2` jar comes bundled with `neo4j-community-2.1.4` and when I add both jars to my project I get the exception.

```
Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /ibet
Info:     file:/home/caleb/NetBeansProjects/qualebs/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_ibetPU logout successful
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_43
```

The first place where this exception is thrown in my code is

```
private static final StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_43);
```

and any other place where I try calling `Version.LUCENE_43`

I am developing in netbeans and as per the instructions on [Include Neo4j in your project](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-setup.html) I am required to copy all jars or add them from netbeans to my project. JDK 8, Java EE 7 Glassfish 4.0. All research I have done including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395004/how-to-use-two-versions-of-jar-in-my-java-project) and [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDAQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgrokbase.com%2Ft%2Fgg%2Fneo4j%2F13c3k3dsq6%2Fhow-can-i-use-neo4j-with-lucene-4&ei=Xj0fVMejJpTjavu7gbgB&usg=AFQjCNHzIuocfOyOxjqF0z2uTpdYSQjI4A&sig2=sx8FZsKzXqU3RHucIoLN1g&bvm=bv.75775273,d.d2s) has led me to conclude that there I no simple way of using both versions of jars in the same JVM. The only option I have is using lucene 3.x and below instead of 4.x or simply postponing implementing graph database for my project until neo4j becomes compatible with future versions of lucene-core. So I ask if these are really the only options? How can I use both jars without running two jvms or use of classloaders for each?

Meanwhile I have tried excluding `lucene-core-3.6.2` from my project and then tried the code below in my `ContextListener` Class to load the class `org.apache.lucene.document.Fieldable` - which is the class that gets NoClassDefFoundError thrown on.

```
 @Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    final ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
    try {
        URL[] urls;
        URL url = new URL("file://" + context.getRealPath("/"));
        URI resolve = url.toURI().resolve("../../../" + "jars/neo4j-community-2.1.4/lucene-core-3.6.2.jar");
        urls = new URL[]{resolve.toURL()};
        URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);
        loader.loadClass("org.apache.lucene.document.Fieldable");

    } catch (MalformedURLException | URISyntaxException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ContextListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    Neo4JDAO.createGraphDbConnection(context.getRealPath("/") + "/graph/");        
}
```

but I still get an exception. I am confused how do I load this class so that it is accessible from everywhere an not only inside the ContextListener's ContextInitialized method?

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /home/caleb/NetBeansProjects/qualebs/build/web/graph

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@1d202bd' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.document.Fieldable
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1761)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
    ... 61 more
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use Neo4j in embedded mode I don't see any way to do this without using proper classloader separation.

Have you considered using Neo4j in server mode and rely on your application using the [transactional Cypher endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html) (or the [JDBC driver](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc)) to communicate with the database? This way you have the full freedom of choosing and dependency in your application.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you for your speedy response. After considering your suggestions, I think I am going to go with JDBC driver. I have also tried to solve the same problem with UrlClassLoader but I can't seem to make it work. I have reviewed and added the code. Could you please help me understand where I am going wrong. Thanking you in advance.