# neo4j and elastic-search in same spring boot project (conflict lucene version)

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, elasticsearch, neo4j

I know this is a duplication of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395004/how-to-use-two-versions-of-jar-in-my-java-project)
but it's been 5 years and maybe someone could suggest other solutions now.

I am trying to coexist `elastic-search` and `neo4j` and there is a conflict with the `Lucene` dependency for both of them.

In my case I have

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

`elasticsearch` depends on `Lucene v7.2.1` and `neo4j` depends on `v5.5.5`

I have tried to exclude `v5.5.5` from `neo4j` package but it didn't work there are some class that aren't found. I have also tried to reduce the version of `Lucene` for `elasticsearch` but it didn't work either.

What really bothers me is that `elasticsearch` is defining a package similar to `Lucene` and I think this is part of the problem.

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

**Update**

What do they mean by `default Java driver` in this sentence from https://neo4j.com/developer/elastic-search/

> If you plan to connect Neo4j to ElasticSearch using the default Java
>   driver, please be aware that there are incompatibilities between the
>   Lucene version used by Neo4j and ElasticSearch, so you might need to
>   go with a REST based solution like JEST.

**Update 2**

If there is no solution to resolve the conflict which option is better for this use case:
I have frontend which will send some `cypher query` to the rest server. The rest server should be able to use the `spring-data` and `OGM mapping` in order to communicate with `Neo4j` and also able to execute the `cypher query` from the `frontend`.

So should I :

- use a `standalone instance` and communicate with it using the `bolt protocole`
- use an `embedded instance` in an other `springboot` project and expose it via `bolt protocol`
  use an `embedded instace` in an other `springboot` project and expose it's rest api

I am searching for solution which assure a good communication speed between the `rest server` and `neo4j instance`. And support the facilities provided by `OGM` from the `rest server`.  The `frontend` will not communicate directly to `neo4j instance`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the `default Java driver`, they mean the neo4j dependency you are including. The one that talks with neo4j directly. Neo4j also have a REST API, they suggest you use JEST (I don't know what that is) that I guess speaks with Neo4j using the REST API and therefore avoid the need to use Lucene at all.

Comment: https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest is HTTP Rest client for ElasticSearch. for me this not a good solution I prefer neo4j HTTP rest client